# C# How to set a int in a another NameSpace and Struct

Tags: c#

I added a dll to my project references and I want to edit an int in the dll. How can I do that?

```
namespace FirstNameSpace
{
    public class ClassName
    {
       //Code to set the int  in the struct
    }
}

namespace SecondNameSpace
{
    private struct StructName
    {
       public int IntName
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot. That struct is private. Also the given code doesn't compile. Please show compiling code

Comment: The code is huge. I was told i can change private stuff using Reflections. Is this true?

Comment: There was ways to access private members, but they are used in peculiar situations - don't do it.